# Flatness and Kinetic Energy

Tags: general-relativity, energy, cosmology, curvature, cosmological-inflation

Why the curvature parameter can be interpreted as the difference between the average potential energy and the average kinetic energy of a region of space?

Curvature parameter:$$\Omega_{k}\equiv\Omega-1=\frac{\rho-\rho_{crit}}{\rho_{crit}},\;\;\;\;where \;\;\rho_{crit}\equiv3H^{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first Friedmann equation (in the absence of dark energy) is:

$$ \left(\frac{\dot{R}}{R}\right)^2 = \frac{8\pi G \rho}{3} - \frac{kc^2}{R^2} \tag{1} $$

Now this is where it all gets a bit arm waving. Suppose we assume everything is slow moving so we can use Newtonian expressions for energy. Take a spherical region of space of radius $R$ and a test mass $m$ at the edge of that region. The spherical region encloses a mas $M$ given by:

$$ M = \frac{4}{3}\pi R^3\rho $$

So the potential energy of our test mass $m$ is:

$$ U = -\frac{GMm}{R} = -\frac{G4\pi R^3\rho m}{3R} = -\frac{4G\pi R^2\rho m}{3} $$

The velocity of our test mass is just $\dot{R}$ so the kinetic energy is:

$$ T = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{R}^2 $$

And the total energy is therefore:

$$ E = \frac{1}{2}m\dot{R}^2 - \frac{4G\pi R^2\rho m}{3} $$

Now we rewite this as:

$$ \frac{1}{2}m\dot{R}^2 = \frac{4G\pi R^2\rho m}{3} + E $$

and multiply both sides by $\tfrac{2}{mR^2}$ to get:

$$ \left(\frac{\dot{R}}{R}\right)^2 = \frac{8G\pi \rho}{3} + \frac{2E}{mR^2} \tag{2} $$

If you compare equation (2) with the first Friedmann equation (1) that we started out with, you'll see the equations are the same if:

$$ - \frac{kc^2}{R^2} = \frac{2E}{mR^2} $$

or:

$$ k = -\frac{2E}{mc^2} $$

The idea of all this is that a flat universe $k = 0$ is one in which the kinetic and potential energy balance so the net energy is zero. Likewise an open universe is one in which the kinetic energy is greater than the (magnitude of) the potential energy so the system isn't bound. A closed universe has $T < |U|$ and is gravitationally bound.

But you should treat this purely as an aid to intuition. The energy of an FLRW universe is an elusive concept and certainly not as simply defined as the above suggests.